Rollback DynamoDB operations with AppSync
I have an Amplify app that will use a third party API to handle payments. If the API succeeds, I want the DynamoDB database to update accordingly. In this app, users buy tickets, and I want to 1. add number of tickets for the user that made the purchase, 2. add a record to the purchase history table, and 3. send the third-party API to handle payments (not necessarily in this order). Obviously, I'd like to implement some sort of transaction to prevent any mismatch in data.
I am aware of TransactWrite of DynamoDB to handle these two DB operations as a transaction, but to my knowledge it is not possible to "involve" the API call within the transaction such that if the API call fails, I can rollback the DB operations.
I believe there is also no way to rollback DB operations, the only way being to basically manually undo the DB operation with another DB operation. So in my use case, it'll be to delete the purchase record and subtract back the tickets owned by the user. I feel this kind of defeats the purpose of atomicity however.
Basically, I am not sure what is the best way to operate these three operation as a single all-or-nothing transaction.
Since I have more control of DynamoDB despite the lack of a rollback function, I believe the order of operation should be as follows:
Run the 2 DB operations as a transaction --> Send API
This way, in case the API call fails, there is at least a way to "rollback" DynamoDB to the state before, albeit the manual way as I have mentioned previously.
Is my understanding of all of this correct? Is there a better way to implement what I want?

You could use dynamodb lock client, to first lock the users items, then send the request to the third party api. Release the lock and transactwrite the items to dynamodb.
If the third party API fails, then you don't have to rollback data, just release the lock.
Or you could use separation of concerns. Perhaps a dynamodb table to save data initially and if the third party API succeeds then write new items to a different table with the payment metadata. The temp table could have a low TTL set where the items will expire for free.

With the first method, what is the procedure in case the transactwrite fails?
